# CMake Errors - Using Conan

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl, conan

I just cant figure out why I am getting this error, would anyone mind giving me some help?

I have added Cmake to the Environment variables, but am still getting an error. I'm currently a University Student trying to get SDL to work.

My machine is x64, I have Visual Studio 2017 with all C++ elements installed.

Here is the CMD error:
[CMD Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UsPl.jpg)

Here is the GUI error:
[GUI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkD19.jpg)

Copy - Paste CMD Version:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Chris Ross/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.8/lasote/stable/build/6cc50b139b9c3d27b3e9042d5f5372d327b3a9f7/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Chris Ross/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.8/lasote/stable/build/6cc50b139b9c3d27b3e9042d5f5372d327b3a9f7/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
zlib/1.2.8@lasote/stable:
zlib/1.2.8@lasote/stable: ERROR: Package '6cc50b139b9c3d27b3e9042d5f5372d327b3a9f7' build failed
zlib/1.2.8@lasote/stable: WARN: Build folder C:\Users\Chris Ross\.conan\data\zlib\1.2.8\lasote\stable\build\6cc50b139b9c3d27b3e9042d5f5372d327b3a9f7
ERROR: zlib/1.2.8@lasote/stable: Error in build() method, line 60
        self.run('%s && cmake .. %s' % (cd_build, cmake.command_line))
        ConanException: Error 1 while executing cd _build && cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCONAN_LINK_RUNTIME="/MD" -DCONAN_EXPORTED="1" -DCONAN_COMPILER="Visual Studio" -DCONAN_COMPILER_VERSION="15" -DCONAN_CXX_FLAGS="/MP4" -DCONAN_C_FLAGS="/MP4" -Wno-dev
INFO: Conan job finished.
INFO: Starting cmake
CMake Error: Error: generator : Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
Does not match the generator used previously: Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.
INFO: CMake job finished.
```

Copy - Paste GUI Version:

```
    CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES              Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo
    CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX                   C:/Program Files (x86)/lab1

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Chris Ross/Desktop/lab2template/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Chris Ross/Desktop/lab2template/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

My conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
SDL2/2.0.5@dotfloat/stable
SDL2_image/2.0.1@lasote/stable
SDL2_mixer/2.0.1@a_teammate/testing
SDL2_ttf/2.0.14@hilborn/stable

[options]
SDL2:shared=True
SDL2_image:shared=False
SDL2_mixer:shared=True
SDL2_ttf:shared=False

[generators]
cmake

[imports]
bin, *.dll -> ./bin # Copies all dll files from packages bin folder to my "bin" folder
lib, *.dylib* -> ./bin # Cop
```

Using this .bat file:

```
@echo off

:start
echo INFO: I am running from '%cd%'
if exist src goto changetobin

:conan
echo INFO: Starting conan
conan install --build missing
echo INFO: Conan job finished.
goto cmake

:cmake
echo INFO: Starting cmake
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
echo INFO: CMake job finished.
goto end

:changetobin
echo ERROR: I'm in the wrong directory.. moving into bin
cd bin
echo INFO: Retrying..
goto start

:end
if exist bin goto quit
cd ..
goto quit

:quit
echo.
echo.
echo INFO: Conan and CMake ran successfully. Open up your solution file (listed below) to open your project.
echo.
dir /b *.sln
```

(I have also attempted a manual build (conan install --build missing))

Comment: The error indicates that CMake cannot find the MSVC compiler installed with visual studio. Can you confirm that you installed VS 2015, and select the C++ compiler as part of its installed components?

Comment: I currently use VS 2017 (C++ is installed and I am able to make projects), my friend recommended i uninstall VS 2015 to fix the problem but it didnt work :/ "Visual Studio 15 2017" has been selected in the CMake gui.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using this conan package for zlib? https://bintray.com/conan-community/conan/zlib%3Aconan/1.2.8%3Astable

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand what this last comment means.

Comment: You also need to provide all the reproducible steps towards this error. Like: 1) this is my conanfile.txt, I am using. 2) I have this setup (machine, compiler, etc) 3) I am executing these commands: "conan install ..." 4) My output is this

Comment: Take into account that the existing SDL package in conan-transit bintray repository might not be perfect. Those packages are provided by the community and are  not reviewed, not guarantee to work. There is an ongoing effort to provide high quality packages in conan-center repository.

Comment: All updated, if there is anything please don't hesitate to ask

Comment: @ChristopherRoss you state that you are using Visual Studio 2017, why then are you generating a solution for VS2015? `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"`

Answer (score 0):

"My machine is x64, I have Visual Studio 2017 with all C++ elements installed."

You're generating a solution for the wrong version of Visual Studio..

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
```

Change that line in your batch script to:

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
```

Then you *must* remove all generated files (`CMakeCache.txt', 'CMakeFiles` dir, etc`) and try again. Please also double check that your conan profile settings match the compiler you are using.

Comment: I did this, still no hope. Exact same error. I've tried all of them, each and every one.

Comment: What I would suggest you try then is uninstalling CMake, removing all its files (verify that `Program Files\CMake` is 100% empty and gone), and reinstalling it where it will re-detect your compiler, and then use the generator for the version of Visual Studio you have installed only. I've felt this pain before and had success by doing a clean reinstall.